# Check function name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
object = {'name' : String}
object = {'age' : Number}
typeof object.name // 'function'
typeof object.age // 'function'
```

Is it possible to check that object.name is a String and object.age is a Number?

Using typeof only gives me back 'function'.

Comment: could you show the code that includes the `typeof`?

Comment: You realize `String` is the actual string constructor, right?  If that's what you want to check, you can just do `object.name == String`.

Comment: i think you might be thinking in Actionscript. In Javascript, the rhs of the property is the value or instance of an object, not a type. eg
`var object = { name: 'geoff', age: 66 };`

Comment: At this point, you might want to look into Microsoft's [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) now that's it been released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than doing:

```
object = {'name' : String}
object = {'age' : Number}
```

You should check for actual data type:

```
object = {'name' : 'test', 'age' : 123}
```

And here is how you can check their type:

```
alert(typeof(object.name));
alert(typeof(object.age));
```

**Output:**

```
string
number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
    "name" : "test",
    "age"  : 123
};

if (!isNaN(parseInt(object.age, 10))) {
    // It is a numerical value (since this is an age, an int may be appropriate)
    alert("It's numeric!");
}
if (object.name.toString() === object.name) {
    // It is really a string
    alert("It's a string!");
}
```